# Magento 2: Create NOT CAPTURE Invoice after Authorize Payment using Braintree

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, plugin, payment-gateway, authorize

I'm using Magento 2.3.4 and Braintree as payment method, i set the payment action configuration to Authorize only, after checkout using this payment method i need to generate a `NOT_CAPTURE` invoice automatically, is there a setting to do this? or is there a way to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

May want to look into this module from plumrocket (i am not affiliated, we use it for one of our clients) and it does exactly that, allows auto invoice rules and one is to set the invoice to Not Capture on order creation.  Hope this helps.

https://store.plumrocket.com/auto-invoice-and-shipment-magento2-extension.html